# Background images are overlapping while fetching from database?

Tags: php, html, css

I am fetching images from the database which is working but all images are overlapping. I want to display all images one by one. Would you help me in this?

```
    .img {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width:  300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-size:     cover;
}

   <?php if ($result_related_products->num_rows > 0) { // output data of each row                                   
          while($row = $result_related_products->fetch_assoc()) {
                      $p_img=$row['p_img'];
                      ?>
                        <div class="img" style="background-image: url('admin/assets/img/products/<?php echo $p_img; ?>')">
                             <?php } 
                              } 
           else { echo "0 results"; } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **close** the DIV

```
</div>
```

(In your while loop)

Comment: Oh god. How can I forgot that div.  I am facing this issue last 1 hour. Thanks for your help Mr.Remco.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close the `div`

change this

```
<div class="img" style="background-image: url('admin/assets/img/products/<?php echo $p_img; ?>')">
```

for this (see at the end of line the `</div>`)

```
<div class="img" style="background-image: url('admin/assets/img/products/<?php echo $p_img; ?>')"></div>
```